# Ubuntu 18.04 problem with opening gnoem-system-monitor

Tags: 18.04, system-monitor

I have one problem with `gnome-system-monitor`. Consol output is:

```
$ gnome-system-monitor 
Gtk-Message: 22:05:03.324: Failed to load module "pantheon-filechooser-module"
Gtk-Message: 22:05:03.325: Failed to load module "pantheon-filechooser-module"
Gtk-Message: 22:05:03.325: Failed to load module "pantheon-filechooser-module"

(gnome-system-monitor:13203): Gtk-WARNING **: 22:05:03.325: cannot open display: :0
```

I have try to reinstall it with snap but nothing, same error in console. Few weeks before i try elementary beta, I might be pulling some tails from than...